# How to apply babel-loader before raw-loader (nested webpack processing)

Tags: webpack

I want to do the following:

1. generate a JS bundle with webpack (using ES6 modules, minification, etc)
2. Load the result as a string (using raw-loader) in another bundle.

Currently, I have to explicitly create two webpack configs and run webpack twice.
Chaining JS compilation with raw-loader (e.g. `!raw-loader!babel-loader`) doesn't seem to work, because raw-loader ignores nested loaders.

Is it possible to join these steps into one, and call a nested webpack processing? Would be cool to have something like this:

```js
// this is supposed to resolve and compile nested-entry-point.js
// and return the resulting code as a string
import compiledJsCode from 'nested-entry-point.js';

// ...
eval(compiledJsCode);
// ...
```

I'm not familiar with Webpack loader API yet. Is it theoretically possible to write such a loader that would allow nested compilation before raw-loader?